# How to design many to many relation in mongodb？

Tags: mongodb

#### The current scene is this:

There is a category table [category], the number of records is only more than 50, almost no increase, and the modification is rare.

There is a product table [product] currently millions of levels, will always increase.

These two are many-to-many relationships. One category will have more products, and each product will have multiple categories.

The category list is almost not changed, and there are about 1000 products in a category, and the list of a category will be changed not frequently.

#### Query requirements:

1. Query all categories (excluding the list of products under the category)
2. Query the category list by product_id
3. Query the product list by category_id

#### Operational requirements:

1. Modify the product list in category (add/delete a product to a category, sort the product list in a category, so the product list in category needs order.)

#### How many-to-many design of this kind of scene is better, there are some points:

**1. If you follow the design of the SQL database, add a Category<-->Product relation table.**

- **[Question]** The order of each category of products is not well maintained. For example, the front-end performs a large-scale adjustment order on a category of products, and then requests it. The  Category<-->Product relation table also needs to add an index field to indicate the order, and needs to update a lot of records. It is not particularly friendly to the operation requirements, is there any What can be optimized?

**2. The way of NOSQL. Add a products:[] directly to the category to indicate a list of items in this category.**

- **[Evaluation]** In the query requirement, there is a requirement to query all categories (excluding the list of products under the category), which will pull out a lot of unnecessary data (products) at one time. Not applicable.

**3. Add products:[] in the Category<-->Product association table**

- **[Question]** This can meet the operational requirements, but if you want to meet the Query requirments-2 [Query the category list by product_id], how to query it and will there be performance problems?

Answer (score 0):

You need a third table (junction table) to complete the relationship. The keys must be primary keys along with a foreign key constraint.

```
       tblProductCategories
       PK product_id FK
       PK category_id FK
```